# Inconsistent dependencies in LLVM

Tags: dependencies, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm writing an IR pass for LLVM which uses dependency analysis, and I'm a little unclear on the meaning of certain things behind the theory of the analysis.

In particular, there's a method `isConsistent()` which, according to the docs:
`Returns true if this dependence is consistent (occurs every time the source and destination are executed).`

I'm wondering then what the conditions are for which a dependency isn't consistent. There are two scenarios I want clarification on:

1. If the distance of a loop carried dependency is a constant value greater than one, does this necessarily imply the dependency isn't consistent? And so any consistent dependency must either be loop independent (does not exist through a loop backedge), or has a constant distance of one?
2. Do there exist loop carried dependencies for which the distance is (at least potentially) greater than one, but the dependence at this distance is still inconsistent? For instance, a loop carried dependency with a distance of two, but the dependence does not consistently hold on every second iteration, due to for instance a conditional. If so, how can I use LLVM to determine if a given dependency fits this description?

Thanks.

Comment: From a quick look at the source, it seems as if the documentation should be `if this dependence is *provably* consistent`. There are useful comments in DependencyAnalysis.cpp, just above each occurence of `Consistent = false`, and a reference to [this paper](http://www.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/lehre/2002SS/uebau2/papers/GoffKennedyTseng-PLDI-1991.pdf).

Comment: thanks for pointing me to this. from looking at the source it seems only the most trivial dependencies can be proved to be consistent, which more or less answers both my questions. Would you agree with that?

Comment: Yes. I'd guess that whoever wrote that pass wanted the pass to run quickly rather than prove 100% of what's possible.